# Using async with request

Tags: node.js, async-await

So I've recently hopped on the async/await train, well attempting to I'm still grasping some concepts.

I've started by switching as much as I can to async/await and the packages that don't offer it yet I found promise versions.

Anyways, I stumbled upon the `request-promise-native` module which is just like request but utilizes promises as I'm sure you can see.

I've been experimenting with using async/await with it and it works but I'm not sure I'm using it right. In fact I'm not even sure if it has advantages over using the promise but this particular function I'm converting has a lot of callbacks so I'm trying to keep the amount of tabs at a minimum.

```
testFunction: async (param) => {
    let results;

    try {
        results = await request(requestOptions);
    } catch (e) {
        return (e);
    }

    // Do stuff with results
```

Now this works and I get the desired result but my question is 1. Is this even the right way to use async/await and 2. Is there any benefit to this over the standard promise offered by the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are indeed using `async/await` correctly. The function definition must be preceded by `async` exactly like you've done, and the `await` operator should precede the code that returns the Promise, exactly like you've done. It is also correct to wrap `await` in a `try/catch` because if the Promise is rejected, the `await` expression will throw the rejected value ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)).
2. The benefit is code that *appears* synchronous, which makes it easier to follow, understand, and reason about.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, it's nice to know I'm using it correctly. I guess it just feels weird with the try/catch but it's much better than the amount of callbacks I had before!